# Grub Doesn't Load after Update

Tags: grub2, wubi, startup, updates

After I updated ubuntu (I believe it was most likely a kernel update) and restarted I selected ubuntu from the windows boot loader (I am using wubi). At this point I would usually land on the grub loader; however, I see something about NTFS file not found and a couple other screens flash then the computer restarts. I have tried pressing ESC right after to try and get some options, but I think grub is just not found or something...

Not sure what is going on.. Any help would be much appreciated :).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay. my room mate experience approximately the same problem. After updating you can't open your os any longer. I think the only solution(which we did) was to use the full install(install from on the hd). I think this is an unresolved bug with wubi.

Comment: Yea this is what I ended up doing. I also was able to mount the wubi partition back and get my data luckily!

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/477104) is the bug report. You might try the solution offered by [comment 90](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/477104/comments/90)

All you need to do is download the file attached to the comment and replace your current C:\wubildr with it.

Also, of note from post 91:

> Please make sure that when you boot the line "insmod ntfs" is commented out or disable it by pressing "e" at the grub boot menu and edit the entry before proceeding.

Comment: I didn't try this, but it seems like a good solution...