# can i install ubuntu in my trial version of windows 7?

Tags: installation

I have installed trial version of windows 7 home premium oem.
which is going to inactivate in next 20 days.
so *can* i install ubuntu in my sonay vaio sve 1511 aen model?
if yes than how to instal? and if after 20 days windows is not activated than do i able to use ubuntu or not?

Comment: How do you plan on installing Ubuntu? The simple answer is yes. (If not using WUBI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do so , in my opinion, would be by Using Wubi. It is the best for people who want to install Ubuntu using a Windows environment.

You may find more details regarding wubi [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) . It is fairly simple and you shouldn't hit a blocker using Wubi.

Comment: Simplest isn't always best. See [differences between wubi and normal installation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation) and [long term use of wubi](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107289/will-long-term-use-of-ubuntu-via-wubi-harm-my-pc).

Comment: thank you. Only thing i want to know does ubuntu work if windows is inactivated after 20 days?

Comment: yes, this would completely replace your windows if you wish to and you could have just Ubuntu in your system.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest dual booting, go to [Ubuntu Download Section](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and choose either 12.04 LTS (Long Term Support) or 12.10.

Once you have downloaded the .ISO (Disc Image), then burn the image to the disc at the slowest speed to ensure that the image is burned with no defects.

Once you have done that, insert the disc and go through the set up instructions showing you how to partition your drive.  You will still have the option to choose Windows 7 on start up, or use Ubuntu.

Comment: only thing i want to know is there any way i can use flash drive to install ubuntu.

Comment: Sure is: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick